# O que há de errado nesse while? O || não tá funcionando

Tags: java

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = input.nextInt();
while ( (str.nextInt() != 5) || (str.nextInt() != 10) ){
    str = input.nextInt()
}
```

O código deveria invocar o método `nextInt()` toda vez que o usuário digitasse algum número diferente de 5 ou 10. O que está acontecendo aqui é que quando digito 5 ou 10 ele continua repetindo, invocando o método `nextInt()`.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. O que você pretende com essa comparação? Edite a pergunta e explique melhor o que esse código faz ou deveria fazer.

Comment: Não tem nada de errado pelo fato da gente não saber o que é esperado ;). Uma breve descrição do que está errado ou a partir da entrada qual é o resultado obtido e qual é o resulado esperado já ajuda muito!

Comment: O código deveria invocar o método nextInt() toda vez que o usuário digitasse algum número diferente de 5 ou 10. O que tá acontecendo aqui é que quando digito 5 ou 10 ele continua repetindo, invocando o método nextInt().

Comment: Então está funcionando perfeitamente. Se é pra continuar se for diferente de 5, OU se for diferente de 10, tá certinho.

Comment: Dica: O que você quer é que seja executado quando o numero for "diferente de 5 **e** de 10" e não "diferente de 5 **ou** de 10"

Comment: Pra você entender melhor: Se for 5, é diferente de 10, então continua. Se for 10, é diferente de 5. Então, continua. Foi isso que vc determinou com esse ||.

Comment: Tente assim `while ( (str.nextInt() != 5) && (str.nextInt() != 10) )`

Comment: Ow!!! Obrigado, resolveu meu problema, mas ainda tô confuso do "e" e "ou". Minha lógica tá horrível.  Desculpa aí pela pergunta mal formulada

Comment: O que confunde um pouco é o fato de usar o NOT `!`, pois a lógica inverte. Um outro jeito de escrever é esse: `while ( !( str.nextInt() == 5 || str.nextInt() == 10 ) )` - "Enquanto não for 5 OU 10, execute" - Estamos usando um OU dentro dos parênteses, e negando o resultado do OU como um todo.

Comment: Faça este exercício: Na frase **"3 é diferente de 5 ? diferente de 10"** qual o artigo(E/OU)  que tem de usar para que ela faça sentido?

Comment: Massa, obrigado pela ajuda que vocês me deram. Nisso, acabei lembrando da tabela verdade no assunto de lógica em matemática, que me ajudou a entender melhor, também.V e V = VV e F = FF e V = FF e F = F-------------V ou V = VV ou F = V  --> Por isso que o loop nunca chegava a ser false.F ou V = VF ou F = Ftem outras também, que esqueci agora, como o do "e se", "implica" e outros, mas vou dar uma olhada depois. Valeu Galera, vocês são show.

Answer (score -1):

O que você precisa entender é que tem **três** comandos `nextInt()` nesse trecho.

Portanto o programa pode chamar **duas vezes** `nextInt()` antes de entrar no `ìf`.

Entendi pela sua explicação que você quer chamar `nextInt()` **uma vez**, ver se o retorno é 5 ou 10, e só aí chamar `nextInt()` uma segunda vez. Algo assim:

```
bool continua = false;
do
{
    int primeiraLeitura = input.nextInt();
    if ( primeiraLeitura != 5 || primeiraLeitura != 10 )
    {
        int segundaLeitura int.NextInt();
        continua = true;
    }
} while (continua);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = input.nextInt();
while ( str != 5) || str != 10) ){
    str = input.nextInt()
}
```

Comment: Seria interessante você adicionar alguma explicação à sua resposta, mesmo que este código seja a solução para a pergunta.